# Error when trying to display image by ashx handler - The image “http://localhost:57157/......” cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code :

HTML : `<img src="thumbCreate.ashx?Id=223" alt="asd" />`

HTTP Handler : `

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        CreateThumbNail(context);
    }
private void CreateThumbNail(HttpContext context)
{
        string resourceId = context.Request.QueryString["Id"];
        context.Response.Write("No resource found for Id = " + resourceId);
        Bitmap original = new Bitmap("C:/Devp/My work/ASHXSampleApp/Images/Desert.jpg");
        int oWidth = original.Width;
        int oHeight = original.Height;

        int preferredWidth = 80;
        int preferredHeight = 100;

        int thumbWidthFactor = oWidth / preferredWidth;
        int thumbHeightFactor = oHeight / preferredHeight;

        int maxFactor = Math.Max(thumbWidthFactor, thumbHeightFactor);

        int thumbNailWidth = oWidth / maxFactor;
        int thumbNailHeight = oHeight / maxFactor;
        Bitmap thumbNailImage = (Bitmap)original.GetThumbnailImage(thumbNailWidth, thumbNailHeight, ThumbNailCallback, IntPtr.Zero);


        context.Response.ContentType = "image/Jpeg";
        thumbNailImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


}`
```

But this code does not display image. When I manually try to run the handler in firefox, it gives me an error : - "The image “http://localhost:57157/ASHXSampleApp/thumbCreate.ashx?Id=223” cannot be displayed because it contains errors." Any idea?

Comment: Please debug your code and update the question with information about what exceptions/messages/values you find.

Comment: There is no exception when I debug handler code. But i cant see the image rendered in html page. When i try to run page in firefox i can see the error in console that - 'Image corrupt or truncated: http://localhost:57157/ASHXSampleApp/thumbCreate.ashx?Id=223'. And when I manually try to run the handler I get the error - 'The image “http://localhost:57157/ASHXSampleApp/thumbCreate.ashx?Id=223” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.'

Comment: I have not done any settings in web.config. Do I need to do any settings in web.Config?

Comment: Well you are writing "No resource found for Id =" into the response everytime and that won't do when you then start to write an image afterwards.

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren - Ohh yes.. That was an issue.. Its working now. Why dont you put ur comment as an answer?

Comment: I added an answer with the same content now, glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from this part of your code.

```
string resourceId = context.Request.QueryString["Id"];
context.Response.Write("No resource found for Id = " + resourceId);
```

You are always adding a string to the response stream and then you write the image data afterwards which will result in a corrupted string. Remove that (or make it conditional so it is added when an error occurs or something) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Does context.Response.WriteFile() work?

Comment: @V4Vendetta : comment privileges with stack?? Anyways tries something like -   context.Response.WriteFile("C:/Devp/My work/ASHXSampleApp/Images/Desert.jpg");. That also dint work.